# Where clause in Linq in List c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a struct like this:

```
struct Test
{
   string name;
   string family;
   public Test...
}
```

in my code I have a list of this struct:

```
List<Test> testList=new List<Test>();
```

I have a linq expression like this:

```
var list =testList.Select(n=>n.Name);
```

but how can I filter this selection by Family of the testList? something like this:

```
var list=testList.Select(n=>n.Name).Where(f=>f.Family=="");
```

this Where clause just apply on selected Names which are a list of string

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Remove the `Select`.

Comment: Or move it to after the `Where`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just put the `Where` before the `Select`:

```
var list=testList.Where(f=>f.Family=="").Select(n=>n.Name);
```

In Linq you need to apply the filter *before* projecting (unless the filter applies to the results of the projection rather than the original collection).

Comment: How to write multiple WHERE conditions for same list?

Answer (score 6):

Filter using `Where` before you select just one property using `Select`. That way, you still get the full object:

```
testList.Where(t => t.Family == "").Select(t => t.Name)
```

After all, `Select` will take the object and then only pass on whatever you return in the lambda. In this case, you only return a string, so you throw all the other information from the `Test` object away. And as such, the information you want to filter on isn’t available anymore.

If you switch that around, you can filter on the test object, and then return only that one string.

Answer (score 2):

Normally when I am checking for an empty value like that, I'll use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`, just in case.

```
   testList.Where(f=> string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Family)).Select(n=>n.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first apply `where` clause and the `select` your desired data:

```
var list=testList.Where(f=>f.Family=="").Select(n=>n.Name);
```